# "First argument must be a string or Buffer"- error when following w3schools' Node.js tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was planning on learning how to set up my own web server with Node.js.
I followed w3schools' Node.js tutorial and it was going fine until I got to the "Node.js File System" part.
(Right in the "beginning" of the tutorial, i know.)

---

The task is to make two files.

1. **demofile1.html**

> ```
> <html>
> <body>
> <h1>My Header</h1>
> <p>My paragraph.</p>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

2. and **demo_readfile.js**:

> ```
> var http = require('http');
> var fs = require('fs');
> http.createServer(function (req, res) {
>   fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
>     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
>     res.write(data);
>     res.end();
>   });
> }).listen(8080);
> ```

---

Simple enough, right? The .js file is supposed to read what's in the .html file, and display it in your browser.

In the previous examples of the same tutorial I just loaded the whatever.js with `node whatever.js` and used `localhost:8080` in my browser to run the script without a hitch, but in this case, chrome just gives me a "This site can't be reached (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)" and it crashes node.js with the following error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:642
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:642:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:617:10)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/home/eddo/nodejs_test/demo_readfile.js:6:9)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
```

---

I tried to do a `res.write(data.toString());` to no avail, and changing it to `console.log(data);` gave me a console output of:

```
undefined
undefined
```

but at least **didn't** give me a "This site can't be reached (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)".

Comment: Must probably be `fs.readFile(__dirname + '/demofile1.html', ... )`

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how to upvote your answer @JonasW. but you have my gratitude. :)

Comment: no worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filepath is sligtly off:

`fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {`

Node looks for `'demofile1.html'` in the home directory instead of the current directory. Instead use

`fs.readFile('./demofile1.html', function(err, data) {`

or better:

`fs.readFile(__dirname + '/demofile1.html', function(err, data) {`

Comment: `__dirname + ` did the trick. And thanks for explaining why. :)